# regular expression java password

Tags: java, passwords, expression

Hey I have searched through stackoverflow and can't seem to find an answer.
I need to check if the typed password only contains letters and numbers.

here's the code

```
System.out.println("Type the Password for the new user: ");
    String password = input.nextLine();

    if (!password.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9]")) {            
         System.out.println("The password must only contain letters and/or numbers");
            showAddUser();
    }else{

             System.out.println("The password is valid");
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!password.matches("^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$")) {
```

What a shame - this regular expression excludes "correct horse battery staple".

http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Randall Munroe  is the best.

Answer (score 1):

With `String.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]")` you're actually matching whether the String contains of exactly one alphanumeric. You probably want it to be repeated. You could try `String.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+")` to match at least one alphanumeric, not exactly one.

By the way, I wouldn't trust a system which doesn't allow me to use punctuation as well.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why wouldn't you trust a system in that situation?

Comment: Not allowing punctuation is a reduction in the strength of passwords. I wouldn't trust a system that does this, as it shows that the guys designing it haven't got a clue about computer security. If you create a 8 characters password out of alphanums, the strength is 62^8. If you allow all ASCII characters, the strength is 95^8 which is 30 times stronger, which means a brute force attack on a random password takes 30 times longer. Why would anyone deny this additional factor to their users? And what's the next fancy idea, limit the password to 8 or 12 characters?

Comment: I would definitely disagree that the simple restriction of passwords to alphanums entirely reduces the strength of those passwords. [Randall does a great job of explaining why](http://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: also not allowing punctuation usually implies the password is being stored as plain text and removing punctuation is an attempt to prevent SQL injection attacks

Comment: (I would also agree, though, that denying the use of punctuation is ridiculous)

Comment: @admdrew You and the xkcd comic right, and that's why I argued *given the same length*. Some ppl, like me, tend to choose 14 random ASCII characters as passwords, which is an entropy of way more than 84 bits. Why would sites deny that to me...

Comment: Yup, totally agreed. Needlessly restricting my input is infuriating.

Comment: @dkatzel While that is a sound reason to some, I do not want to agree that the inability of making a system proof to one flaw (SQL injection) justifies the introduction of one more flaw on top of it (forcing reduced entropy on the user which then the user has to compensate with longer password length).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the negation:

```
if (password.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9]")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative approach: you can use StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(String str)

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isAlphanumeric%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: It works. But why adding a library when adding a '+' sign to the source code in the right place will also do.

Answer (score 0):

try `if (!password.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9]+"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VT password](https://code.google.com/p/vt-middleware/wiki/vtpassword) library for password validation. You can use AllowedCharacterRule or RegexRule for this. With this tool you can easily add more rules if needed later.